# How to change active link css class (is-active)

Tags: 8, theming

What the best way to change css class for an active link from 'is-active' to (in my case) 'active'?

Also, need I really to replace it or to append my class? I know the 'is-active' class is hard-coded ([here](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.1.x/core/misc/active-link.js#L54) and in several php classes) and it is so strange for me since drupal is overloaded with many abstraction layers and tons of settings. What is it: "legacy of the past" or really well-founded idea?

I need 'active' class just for my current css-framework, but may be 'is-active' used in core or so?

Thank you!

Comment: I really believe that is 'well-founded idea', look in theme.inc file, function `template_preprocess_links` (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_links/8). There is way to change this class changing just one file from core (for anon) and implementing a theme hook (for users). If you really get into, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the theme_menu_link function like this:

```
function theme_menu_link($variables)
{
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($element['#below']);
  }

  foreach ($element['#attributes']['class'] as &$class) {
    if ($class == 'is-active') {
      $class = 'active';
      break;
    }
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  return '<li' . new Attribute($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```